# Arduino Galileo intel: 'DDRB' was not declared in this scope

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide, arduino-c++

I'm using board Intel® Galileo Gen 2, but doesn't run my code, I need to do on up (LEDs) on this way:

```
void setup() {
  DDRB = B111111;  //8-13 como salidas
  DDRC = B111111;  //A0-A5 como salidas
  DDRD = B11111110; //0-6 como salidas, 7 como entrada

  PORTB = B000000;    // LOW en pines 8-13
  PORTC = B000000;    // LOW en pines A0- A5 
  PORTD = B11111110;  // HIGH en pines 0-6, LOW en pin 7 BYTE
}

void loop() {

}
```

get out this error:

```
'DDRB' was not declared in this scope
'DDRC' was not declared in this scope
'DDRD' was not declared in this scope
```

Comment: those are AVR ATmega MCU registers you try to use. The Galileo has a different MCU

Comment: I was looking at it, but I don't know how to find the port register for this board

Comment: why not use Arduino functions?